# Where to put metadata in use with EF and global resources

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, localization, metadata

I have a project with a website and a assembly project containing logic functions used by several other projects.

The entity framework model is in the logic project so it can be used between projects.
I have also created partial classes here with Metadata (display name, required attributes and such).

So far so good.. But now when I'm implementing localization I need to get the display names from the global resources, which is in the website project. Even if there is some way to add a reference to this, it would make a circular reference.

Anyone got a good idea of how to set this up? It's not to late to move the metadata to the website if that is what I should do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't put any globalization or formatting attributes on your models. You should use View Models inside your web tier. Those view models are classes which are specifically tailored to the needs of a given view. It is those view models that will contain attributes about the formatting and globalization required by this specific view.

So here's the usual controller action workflow:

1. The action queries a repository to fetch a model
2. The action maps this model to a view model
3. The action returns passes this view model to the view

To ease the mapping between your models and view models you could use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Is it still partials you are talking about or do you recommend a whole new model for each view, not using my EF object at all? What about reusing code between for example Create and Edit, they pretty much use the same display names and requirements.

Comment: @Andreas, I am talking about a view model for each view. And, of course that you are reusing your models. Look at point 1. in my answer. As far as Create and Edit is concerned you should also have a different view model because those two actions are not the same. For example in the Create action there won't be an Id field whereas in the Edit action not only that there will be an Id field but it will be required => even the validation logic will be different. So view model per view. That's my philosophy.

Comment: So I really shouldn't use my entity framework models, just create view models which resembles these (e.g. without the ID field for the create view), and then map the attributes between the EF model and the view model when for example saving something. Have i understood that correctly?

Comment: @Andreas, yes, that's pretty much it.